# Collect date+hour on every status change

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time

Is there a way to write date and hour on a column on every status change in sharepoint?

Example:

STATUS A -> write date+hour on column A

STATUS B -> write date+hour on column B

STATUS C -> write date+hour on column C

Like:

```
=IF(Status=READY;"DATE+HOUR";"")
```

I need to record date and hour on every status change.
Regards

Comment: You can achieve this easily using Power Automate or SharePoint designer workflow.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap I'm not an expert, could you explain it better or give me an example of the flow?

Comment: Check the reference link given for updating date columns in microsoft flow in my answer and general flow steps as given in Diksha's answer at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/281780/calculated-column-prevent-date-from-changing-sharepoint-2013-online/281785

Comment: Those flow steps are given in sharepoint designer workflow. you can achieve the same using power automate/microsoft flow.